# Need MotionLayout Reference using DataBinding Tree

Tags: kotlin, android-motionlayout

I'm trying to get the reference to my `MotionLayout` inside a `Fragment` inside my `RecyclerView` so that I can attach my `addTransitionListener`. I've got the listener prepared, but I don't know the valid path to this object.

I've seen many great examples that reference `motionLayout` vars, but I can't seem to get a valid one using `DataBinding` methods.

**My RecyclerView is inside my Fragment as:**

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/shipper_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:background="@color/mainList"
                tools:listitem="@layout/row_shipper_line"
                />
```

**My MotionLayout is inside my "row_shipper_line" as:**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout
    android:id="@+id/line_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="@color/mainList"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/row_shipper_line_container_scene"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
```

**My binding var is set as:**

```
binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            inflater,
            R.layout.create_shipper_fragment,
            container,
            false
        )
```

**I've got this code entered and it compiles, but the events aren't called:**

```
rec = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.shipper_list, null)

ml = rec.findViewById(R.id.line_container)

var transitionListener = object : MotionLayout.TransitionListener {

     override fun onTransitionStarted(p0: MotionLayout?, startId: Int, endId: Int) {
                Log.d("MyApp", "Transition onTransitionStarted.")
            }

     override fun onTransitionChange(
                p0: MotionLayout?,
                startId: Int,
                endId: Int,
                progress: Float
            ) {
                Log.d("MyApp", "Transition onTransitionChange.")
            }

     override fun onTransitionCompleted(p0: MotionLayout?, currentId: Int) {
                Log.d("MyApp", "Transition onTransitionCompleted.")
            }

      override fun onTransitionTrigger(
                p0: MotionLayout?,
                triggerId: Int,
                positive: Boolean,
                progress: Float
            ) {
                Log.d("MyApp", "Transition onTransitionTrigger.")
            }
        }

 ml.setTransitionListener(transitionListener)
```

My line swipes LEFT perfectly. I just need to listen for `onTransitionComplete`.

My `binding` tree looks like this:

`Fragment` containing my `RecyclerView` -> Row Layout containing the `MotionLayout` tag.

**What I'm trying to do is something like this:**

```
binding.shipper_list.line_container
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Take a look at the RecyclerView/MotionLayout examples here:
https://github.com/androidx/constraintlayout/tree/main/demoProjects/ExamplesRecyclerView
It does not use data binding but the pattern should be similar.

Comment: This is the bummer with 80% of the example code, it's in Java and no one seems to be using Data Binding in any of these. My MotionLayout animates the line perfectly. I just can't get a reference to the MotionLayout object to attach the onTransitionComplete call to find out when it reaches it's delta of 100%. Appreciate the response.

Comment: We generally pick the lowest common denominator to create our examples. 
Using for example databinding or kotlin  will confuse people who do not. 
Where as most Kotlin users know Java.  I guess this is really a question about data binding.

Comment: Totally understand your position, and super appreciate the work. Data binding is a beautiful way to use Kotlin, but in these cases, it can get confusing to make standard references to objects that are easily accessible when using non-binding methods...it would seem.

Comment: Could you use binding.root.findViewById(R.id.line_container)?   (I have never tried it.) 
It is kind of ugly to have to hop back to findViewById but it might work.

Comment: Brilliant idea. I tried using binding.root.findViewById<MotionLayout>(R.id.line_container), but it comes back null. I can't seem to use it without casting it. It then errors that it can't cast the RecyclerView as a MotionLayout. Oddly, that id node is a MotionLayout XML tag. Confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution by experimenting. The key is to place the transition listener inside the list adapter class during `onBindViewHolder`. Again, this is the only solution I've found if you're using **DataBinding** inside a Fragment. It immediately works. After further consideration, having this handler inside the list adapter class makes far more sense to keep things encapsulated.

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ShipperViewHolder, position: Int) {

    holder.bind(shippers[position])

    var ml = holder.itemView.findViewById<MotionLayout>(R.id.uldMotionLayout)

    var transitionListener = object : MotionLayout.TransitionListener {

        override fun onTransitionStarted(p0: MotionLayout?, startId: Int, endId: Int) {
            Log.d("MyApp", "Transition onTransitionStarted.")
        }

        override fun onTransitionChange(
            p0: MotionLayout?,
            startId: Int,
            endId: Int,
            progress: Float
        ) {
            Log.d("MyApp", "Transition onTransitionChange.")
        }

        override fun onTransitionCompleted(p0: MotionLayout?, currentId: Int) {
            //viewToVibrate.vibrate()
            Log.d("MyApp", "Transition onTransitionCompleted.")
        }

        override fun onTransitionTrigger(
            p0: MotionLayout?,
            triggerId: Int,
            positive: Boolean,
            progress: Float
        ) {
            Log.d("MyApp", "Transition onTransitionTrigger.")
        }
    }

    ml.setTransitionListener(transitionListener)
}
```